# Graphical Layout Scroll Problem in Eclipse Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to develop an android application. I've put a scroll view as main container using graphical layout in eclipse. After that, I had put some UI elements, like buttons. When the total height of elements become more than viewable area, it can be seen using scroll view as expected. There is no problem until this point. The problem is the elements that are not fit viewable are of the screen can not be seen using graphical container of the eclipse interface. There is no problem with the source code, as it runs expectedly. Is there any option in the Eclipse gui to see the UI elements that are not fit the viewport?

Comment: The question is quite unclear like this. Please add your XML code, that might help a bit.

Comment: I tried to make it clear, since English is not my native language, it becomes a little hard for me to easily explain my problem. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I know what you're talking about. When you're viewing the xml file on the Eclipse Graphical layout you can only see the elements that fit on the screen. You can't scroll down to see the entire UI.

I use Eclipse at home and work. I'm using Eclipse Helios Service Release 1, on both systems. For some reason at home, when I'm on the graphical layout, there's a button on the upper right of the graphical viewer that says something like 'Remove Clipping'. (I'm at work now. So can't look to see exactly what it says).

When I click that button, I can now scroll down to see the entire UI. However, on my copy of Eclipse at work that same button isn't displayed. I've tried to figure out what the difference is between the setup on the two copies of Eclipse. But so far haven't been able to figure it out. Note, I've tried viewing the same exact xml file, within the same project, on both copies of Eclipse.

The problem seems to only occur when you're using a scrollview and all the ui elements won't fit on the graphical layout screen within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I've been unable to troubleshoot, so I've resorted to using my physical device instead. I try to get the bulk of work done within the the Eclipse GUI... then nudge and polish with my device. Its a PITA to be sure, uploading what seems like a million times only to move one element a tiny bit more.

Best practices recommend developing on a device. Further, the Layout-tools && scrollView basically make it mandatory to *really* know what is going on. I can't seem to form this into a coherent search argument as my Google-fu has let me down on this one.

BTW - I'm using the shiny new r10 ADT plugin and I've been struggling with this for about 6 months.

Another workaround: You can use a smaller-ish tablet port in the GUI to get a really rough idea of what you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

If your target layout is for a phone or smaller device, simply switch the preview to a larger  screen size configuration.

In the upper left corner, under where it says 'Editing config: ~default', The list provides you with a number of screen sizes to target.  Pick the 10.1 in version, and it will scale the preview, and will then allow you to see and work with all of the views that have scrolled off the screen.

Cheers-

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an old topic but I was having the same issue. I have 2 apps made from outsourcing. when I opened each in eclipse one would show the full contents of the scrollview and one was clipped off. After numerous google searches nothing came up as a solution. I just happen to look and saw the app that is clipped was android version 1.6 and the app that shows everything like i wanted it to so I can use the graphical layout for a scrollview was android verion 2.1.

So i changed the one app to version 2.1 and it fixed it. noone seemed to address that. so for me the fix was make sure the android version you are building for is 2.1. you can always change it back to 1.6 compatable after you are done designing.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way i could figure out is to give negetive top margin to the root layout that will make the rest of the content visible. This is only for dev purpose and should be removed when completed