# Unable to scroll the scrollview in GUI Designer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-scrollview

In my Android application, I have a `ScrollView`. This view includes more than what screen can show. To see the rest, I need to scroll down. But, in android GUI Designer, I am unable to scrollDown the `ScrollView`, because I can't see any option to do that.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027340/graphical-layout-scroll-problem-in-eclipse-android-development) but I can't find the *Clipping* option they have mentioned.  So, how can I scroll in Android GUI designer and design the rest of my application? I am using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Android GUI designer you can not show Scroll but when you run app on device or emulator you can see it so please check on either device or emulator..

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like something that needs to be checked in the emulator or on a phone. The GUI designer is not meant to be interactive or the end-all-be-all. It's supposed to give you a general idea of what it's going to look like live.